# How to dynamically change database password used by a DataSource, which is in turn used by a spring transaction manager

Tags: java, spring, transactional, apache-commons-dbcp

How can I dynamically (at run time) change the DB username and password used by a DataSource when using a Spring transaction manager?

We are using Spring and have a BasicDataSource and a TransactionManager defined as follows for handling database connections and transactions:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="url" ref="dbUrl"/>
    <property name="username" ref="someUsername"/>
    <property name="password" ref="somePassword"/>
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
            p:dataSource-ref="myDataSource" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

We need to support dynamically changing the password that we are using at runtime.  Note that I am not trying to change the password in the DB; that has already happened outside of the application.  I am trying to tell my application to switch passwords that it is using to connect to the DB.

I tried extending BasicDataSource and calling setUsername() and setPassword(), but it appears that changing the username and password have no effect.  I can see by looking into the implementation of BasicDataSource that the username and password appear to only be used when it initially constructs the connection pool.

I then found org.apache.commons.dbcp2.datasources.SharedPoolDataSource and thought that would be the answer to my problems.  But it looks like DataSourceTransactionManager takes a javax.sql.DataSource, which surprisingly SharedPoolDataSource is not.

I can't find any other transaction managers that would take a SharedPoolDataSource or even a javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource.

Is there a way to use a transaction manager and a connection pool and dynamically change the DB password that is used?

Comment: Are you trying to change the user with which you are connecting to the database, or changing the password of the user that you are connecting to the database. In the second case, the DB user should have privileges for changing passwords. This is done usually by administering the database. I'm not sure that is allowed.

Comment: @golyadkin I'm not trying to change the password in the DB; I'm just trying to get my DataSource to start using a new password that is already set in the DB.  I can't see any way to get a BasicDataSource to update the password it is using, and I can't find another DataSource that supports password changes.

Comment: Why do you need to do it dynamically? It must be the case that someone changes the user password regularly, but then the program doesn't know when when to set the new password, and doesn't know when to call your proposed code to change the password. Additionally, how could it be informed or provided with the password? I recommend just typing it in.

Comment: You'll need to create a fascade `DataSource` that allows you to swap the underlying `DataSource` on demand. Should be fairly trivial - the main consideration will be blocking working and draining existing work before roating.

Comment: I would think that any DataSource would use the updated login/password when it needs to create new connections, either to extend the pool, or to renew stale connections.  So, if you were using a DataSource that renews stale connections and/or tests them before use each time, it would replace the old connections tied to the old user/password with new ones, using the updated user/password, as needed...

If BasicDataSource doesn't offer either feature, try using c3p0?

Comment: @moilejter you may find that modern data sources will delegate to the underlying database native data source. For example `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource` and `org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource` - these will store the credentials they are created with.

Comment: But Boris - often those aren't full-fledged datasources with connection pooling.  In particular, PGSimpleDataSource does not support connection pooling.  I don't think MysqlDataSource does either - but MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource does.

Comment: @moilejter kinda my point. The connection pool pools the connections, the native datasource creates them!